# Set thread priority for job in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler

I have a job running on a grails app that I need to run with lower priority. Is there a configuration to set that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the priority on a Quartz trigger like this:

```
myTrigger.setPriority(10);
```

If the priority is not set explicitly, it defaults to 5. In Grails, you can presumably (I haven't tested this) specify this within the `triggers` closure of the job class like this:

```
class MyJob {

    def execute() { 
        println "Job running!"
    }

    static triggers = {
            simple name:'highPriority', priority: 10, startDelay:10000, repeatInterval: 30000, repeatCount: 10
            cron name:'lowPriority', priority: 1, startDelay:10000, cronExpression: '0/6 * 15 * * ?'
    }
}
```